# how to perform string methods on an ajax GET return

Tags: php, ajax

Greeting, fellow programmers,
I have a problem.... keep in mind that I'm completely self-taught, so this may be a stupid question, but I've done hours of research and no one seems to have had the same problem..
I'm working on a php project and I need to be able to perform and ajax GET request, but then store the response as a string variable and perform some string methods on it. Is this possible? And if so, how do I do it.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I've been using JQuery's .load() method to perform GET's and POST's.

Comment: This isn't actually a problem, which is why you haven't been able to find anything. It's your lack of knowledge in javascript. Learn javascript, then ajax, then come back to this and laugh at this question... Honestly.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not completely ignorant in the languages. I know JavaScript quite well, but when it comes to implementing Ajax, I haven't been having the best of luck finding answers. And yes, I know AJAX is not it's own language. Is it possible or is it not?

Comment: Make a request and get the response. Do whatever kind of manipulations you want on it, what else is there?

Comment: It is... as I said. You just need to make a request and get the response.

Comment: Any kind of sample script you could possibly submit? Unless "var example = $("#stuff").load("example.txt");" is a valid way of doing it...

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't use `load()`. I'd use `ajax()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following could be a better approach than using the `.load` function if you have to use it for other things than just interacting with the DOM.

```
$.get("from-page.php", function(data) {
    var manipulated = data.substring(data.length, Math.ceil(data.length / 2));
    //any kind of manipulations you want

    $("#div").html(manipulated);
});
```

Comment: The actual purpose of this is that I need to have JavaScipt retrieve css styles from the stylesheet onLoad and save it to sessionStorage, then the user uses a GUI to edit those styles, and they continue to be changed inside sessionStorage. When they save, it gets retrieved from sessionStorage and POSTed to a php file that overwrites the previous css stylesheet. If they leave the page, it saves to localStorage, so the data isn't lost. So, which one is better for me since I need it for that purpose?

Comment: That seems pretty advanced. You're overriding the css style sheet instead of using cookies?

Comment: The changes need to be permanent once committed, and not local to the computer of the person who made the changes. So yes.

Comment: Are you allowing the css text to be in a php file? Maybe you could drop the whole localStorage thing and just post with ajax to the php file (rendered as a css file to the browser with `header("Content-type: text/css");`) using an auth key if required and changing the values like that.

Comment: Wait...I can do that?? I can just tell the browser that my php script is a stylesheet?

Comment: Yeah, you can. Change the `Content-type` header

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you read the docs but it's in [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Look for **Example: Display a notice if the Ajax request encounters an error.**

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

`response` should contain the string you want to manipulate.